# Running a fake redis for a python functional test running in a subprocess

Tags: python, testing, redis, mocking

I am writing a functional test for a program that reads data from stdin and then pushes it onto a Redis Queue. I have unittests, but also want a functional test that tests the whole process.

Ideally I don't want to have to run a real Redis server for the tests since installing and starting Redis is platform dependent. So is there a way I can have a fake redis server somehow that I can use in my test to see if "myprogram" indeed pushed something onto the right Redis key?

This is what my functional test looks like:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE


def test_stdin():
    """Test sending data to stdin of LoraProcessor."""
    with Popen(["python3", "myprogram/myprogram.py"],
               stdin=PIPE) as proc:
        proc.communicate("some stdinline")
```

Comment: As you are calling a external program with `Popen`, mock won't help you. Anyway, take a look at [fakeredis](https://github.com/jamesls/fakeredis)

Comment: Why don't you write a test for `myprogram/myprogram.py` classes and functions instead of call it by `Popen`?

Comment: because it is a program that reads from stdin (as you can see). In real life, that is what the program does, take data on stdin and processes it. So that is what I want to test in a functional test. I know I can also (and do) unittest directly. i just want an additional test that actually sends data to stdin. If you have a suggestion how I can do that, that'd be great.

Comment: Well, if you use a an external config file to define settings like servers, you could set a file of settings for tests, and use it as env preparation to run your tests.

Answer (score 0):

you could give https://pypi.org/project/fakeredis/ a try to use it in unittests.

> Fake implementation of redis API for testing purposes.